# Distinct the data model from ArraList to post the data to sever in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, http-post

My ArrayList is like the attached image. 
So, I want to distinct the list and need to post the data to server. 
So I have created the Serialized model class like

```
 @SerializedName("VehicleList")
public List<VehicleList> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();

public static class VehicleList {

    @SerializedName("VehicleNumber")
    public String vehicleNumber;

    @SerializedName("Mileage")
    public String mileage;

    @SerializedName("Coupons")
    public List<Coupons> coupons = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static class Coupons {

    @SerializedName("Code")
    public String code;
}
```

[image]

My ArrayList like this

```
List<CodeItem> mList = new ArrayList<CodeItem>();
```

code item look like this

```
public class CodeItem {

private String code;
private String status;
private String vehicleID;
private String mileage;
private String date;
public boolean selected;

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getVehicleID() {
    return vehicleID;
}

public void setVehicleID(String vehicleID) {
    this.vehicleID = vehicleID;
}

public String getMileage() {
    return mileage;
}

public void setMileage(String mileage) {
    this.mileage = mileage;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

Now I want to distinct the data for vehicle id and post it to sever. So how do I distinct the data  by VehicleID from this mList?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `distinct the data for vehicle id` ... can you show, by way of example data, what two distinct vehicle ids look like?

Comment: I have to get the [vehicle id =test, mileage = test , {test1 , test2}],  [vehicle id =test2, mileage = test2 , {test1 , test2}] 
Like this I need to distinct the data to post

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  I asked you to clarify with data, but you seem to be reluctant in providing it.

Comment: No no, I think you are not get my question, 
I have the arraylist like the image. So each vehicleID have multiple codes in the list. So, I have to get get the codes list for vehicleid. Then I should post it to server. 

For ex - Test vehicle ID has 3 codes, So I need to distinct then set the values to vehicleList to post the data

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you suggest the idea ?